# Blockchain Testnet tokens, where do they come from and are they unlimited?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, bitcoin-testnet

This might be a dumb question but I cannot find an answer and I'm really curious about it.
So there are many test networks like Rinkeby, Kovan, Ropsten etc ... These testnets offer free tokens (Faucet), but many of them offer some small amounts that are not enough for a lot of testing.
I have many questions ...

Where does this "faucet" come from ?
Is it unlimited ? If not, why not ... ? If it is only for testing and has no value, why are we limited to get only specific (sometimes very small) amounts of test token ?
Can anyone create a testnet with free tokens ?

I have a lot of questions but I will limit myself to these ones for now.

Comment: ive wondered the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin testnet is a separate blockchain with mining and transactions. It has its own rules for adjusting difficulty so that transactions happen even with few miners.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet

> Testnet2 was just the first testnet reset with a different genesis
> block, because people were starting to trade testnet coins for real
> money.

That's hilarious. So yes, those are coins with mostly the same features on a separate blockchain. As with mainnet, their supply is limited and they have to be mined.

Can anyone create a testnet? Sure, you can make your own:

Bitcoin:
https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box

Ethereum and others:
https://www.ulam.io/blog/how-to-setup-custom-ethereum-testnet/